# Insert a csv file into sql with a date in path

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using to add csvs files in my table:

```
load data local infile 'path/file.csv' into table table_name fields terminated by ';' enclosed by '"' ignore 1 lines;
```

But I have a folder with a date where I save this file. I create a folder each day with the date as a name. How can I add this date to be recognized alone?

I tried something like this (like in VBA), but I recived an error message:

```
'path/' & format(now(),"dd") & '/' & format(now(),'mm') & format(now(),'yyyy') & '/file.csv'
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that there are mixed double-quotes and single quotes?

'path/' & format(now(),"dd") & '/' & format(now(),'mm') & format(now(),'yyyy') & '/file.csv'

"dd" vs 'mm' vs 'yyyy'

Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: This not works, I also tried:
load data local infile 
'C:/Users/rocket/Documents/filipe ferminiano/processos/segmentacao/' & DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%d') & DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%m') & DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%y') & '/tirza_customer.csv' 
into table crm_base.tirza_customer fields terminated by ';' ignore 1 lines;

Error message: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '& DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%d') & DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%m') & DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%y')' at line 2